# Intel XDK jquery mobile go back to previous sub page

Tags: jquery-mobile, intel-xdk

I am using Intel XDK with jquery mobile and I am trying to override the hardware back button because it is not working. I am not sure how much of my code I can post. I do have a complicated app though. I have three html files. With an index.html with links (hrefs) to page one and page two. In index.html I have this code

```
script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="xhr.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery v2.1.1 -->
<script src="jqm/jquery.mobile-min.js"></script> <!-- jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Intel native bridge is available */
    var onBackKeyDown = function() {
        $.mobile.goBack();
    }
    var onDeviceReady = function() { 
        intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen(); 
        intel.xdk.display.useViewport;
        intel.xdk.device.addVirtualPage();
        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.hardware.back", onBackKeyDown, false);
    };
    document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
</script>
```

On page one and page two currently I have about ten subpages each (more to come) and I definitely want to back able to go back to the previous subpage. I have done kind of a lot of work with jquery mobile so far and I hope I don't have to switch to App Framework just to get the back button to work. Thanks for any help, let me know if you need any more html code or JS.

Comment: What platforms have you tried it on?  E.g. Android, iOS?  Have you tried it in the emulator, or on devices, and if the latter, through AppPreview, Debug tab or installed App?